# My function returns only one line from the file instead giving all the lines in the file

Tags: python, regex, function

I have written a Function to read each line in .csv file to convert into array.

First three lines of MY file

```
GTCAAGCATACCCCCGAGCATAGCCAGAGGCTAGTTCTACGCGGTGTAGGTGGCCGACAGCTTCGCGGCCCAAGGATGAGATCAGTAAACCCCGTTGGCAGAAATCTATGTTCATT
AGCCTGGTGCAGGTAGCGCAGCTGCTAAGGTCCCTATCGCGGTAGA
AACACTTGGTCCGACACAATTTTTTGTCTCTGCGAGTTTTGTGTGA
```

Code I have written

```
import re
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
def test(logfile):
    with open(logfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.lower()
            line = re.sub('[^acgt]', 'z', line)
            my_array = np.array(list(line))
            label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
            label_encoder.fit(np.array(['a','c','g','t','z']))
            integer_encoded = label_encoder.transform(my_array)
            onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, dtype=int, n_values=5)
            integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
            onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
            onehot_encoded = np.delete(onehot_encoded, -1, 1)
            return onehot_encoded
```

It only returns me first line in the file instead of returning all the lines in the file. Can you please help me to return array for the all the lines in the line

Comment: Your return is inside the loop. So it runs the loop once and returns... This is basic programming in any language.

Answer (score 2):

Your return is inside the loop. So it runs the loop once and returns

You need to declare a variable outside of the loop and append to that.
Then after the loop return the populated array

```
import re
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
def test(logfile):
   out_arr = [] # <-- object to hold output.
   with open(logfile) as f:
       for line in f:
           line = line.lower()
           line = re.sub('[^acgt]', 'z', line)
           my_array = np.array(list(line))
           label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
           label_encoder.fit(np.array(['a','c','g','t','z']))
           integer_encoded = label_encoder.transform(my_array)
           onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, dtype=int, n_values=5)
           integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
           onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
           onehot_encoded = np.delete(onehot_encoded, -1, 1)
           out_arr.append(onehot_encoded) # <--- append instead of return
   return out_arr # <-- now that the loop is over, return the whole array
```

Comment: I didnot notice my return statement is in the loop. Thanks for the solution it worked.